# Mirror pages from closed excel workboot

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build an excel workbook that pulls 5 sheets from a closed workbook, original workbook has about 20 sheets.

- Both files are in the same location, and I would like to keep all the same formatting in the original book. So I need mirror sheets.
- The new workbook needs to be able to refresh/sync with the original every time its open. (I can always as a sync macro, that’s no problem)

It would be easy to link the cells, but I would need to have both files open. I really need to avoid this if possible.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would either (1) Just link the required cells rather than the entire sheets which should still be very quick. See [this method](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_4003-Quickly-creating-a-summary-differential-sheet-or-linked-output-sheet-ignoring-any-blank-cells.html) (2) Use a `vbs` shortcut to open up the original file instead and remove the redundant sheets